# Query to get date count

Tags: sql, oracle9i

Suppose I am having 3 set of records

```
key1    start_date1     start_date2    start_date3
701 08-SEP-2009 08-DEC-2009    08-jan-2010
701 08-JUN-2013 08-SEP-2013    08-DEC-2013
701 08-MAR-2017 08-MAR-2018    31-DEC-1899
```

So i need to get a count of changed date greater than `14-apr-2011`.
i.e. for particular key `701`, there are  changed date count as `5`

i.e. for 3 set of rows, the dates greater than `14-Apr-2011` are of 5 counts.
I need to get a table output with two fields as

```
Key1  changedcount
701      5
```

Please help me regarding this..i was tryin for this for more than 2 days :(

Comment: How do you get the count 5 from the above result set..?

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like the following :

```
SELECT SUM(nb)
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) nb FROM your_table WHERE start_date1 > '14-Apr-2011'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT COUNT(*) nb FROM your_table WHERE start_date2 > '14-Apr-2011'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT COUNT(*) nb FROM your_table WHERE start_date3 > '14-Apr-2011')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  key1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN start_date1 > '14-Apr-2011' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) +
  COUNT(CASE WHEN start_date2 > '14-Apr-2011' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) +
  COUNT(CASE WHEN start_date3 > '14-Apr-2011' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS changedcount
GROUP BY key1
FROM atable
```